# Robocopy only copy folders modified in last 7 days

Tags: robocopy

I'm trying to create a robocopy program that runs every Sunday and pulls in the last 7 days of folders(and its sub-folders) .this is because the folder stores years' worth of data so I only want to pull in the new folders.
is there a way to do this? I've been playing around with the max/min age but its pulling in all folders

what i have so far:

```
robocopy \\myserver\test\main_folder \\myserver\test\main_folder_archive /MIR
```

I want to run this every Sunday and it is smart enough to pull in the last 7 days.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> robocopy \server\source_share \server\dest_share /MAXAGE:7 /S /E

Should do it. This is not compatible with /MIR though:

> /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.

So either mirror, or select 7 days worth of files.

Edit: added /S, which is what I think was the desired switch instead of /MIR

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. i tried dropping the /MIR command, however i believe i need this as the fils i need to copy over are within a number of sub folders and i also need to bring the sub folders over as well. when i dropped the /MIR command, it would only copy over files that were not in a folder, is this correct?

Comment: aha - then you want /S to bring across the subdirectories, not /MIR. My usual command to recursively copy a folder to a new location is "robocopy \\server\sourceshare \\server\destshare /e /s /r:0"
/s copies subdirs, /e copies empty subdirs, and /r:0 tells it to not retry

Comment: that worked perfectly thank you! it takes some time to run(around 15 mins) as it has to go through each folder but once complete, only 7 days old and earlier folders copy over to my destination folder! thank you!